# xml : unable to track down invalid char

Tags: xml, xslt, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to transform an xml file via xslt, but am unable to track down a char that is causing the the parser to choke on the file. during the transform, I get this error:

```
myfile.xml:1: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xBC 0x29 0x20 0x69
g said premises on the West which does not encroach over one and one quarter (1 
                                                                           ^
unable to parse myfile.xml
```

when I search at that spot in different editors, some editors understand the code and display its rendered character:

```
over one and one quarter (1 ¼)
```

and other editors do not and display the default system char:

```
uarter (1 &#xfffd;)
```

I can manually search the file to that spot, and in the case of that char determine that it's [supposed to be](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bc/index.htm) `&#188;`, but I would like to be able to find and replace those chars before the transform is run.

Is there anyway to determine what that replacement should be given the byte info above?

this is the xml prolog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

when I take the above string and create a char array and byte array in java I get

```
char : ¼ bytes -68
```

and if I do a test:

```
if (c == '\u00BC') {
            System.out.println("matched one quarter!");
}
```

then it matches...is there simply a way to loop over in java and do the find/replace that way?

the find/replace needs to be done prior to the xslt transform, as a parse error will choke the process before it starts; I think the overall question, is what is the best way to identify that bad chars and replace them with decimal entities? as shown above, some editors render the char, others throw an error and replace with '?' or some other system char.

I think the java char test above seems like the best solution so far.

Comment: What does the XML declaration on the file say? How is the file being generated in the first place? How does the offending section look like in a hex editor?

Comment: *"I would like to be able to find and replace those chars before the transform is run."*  Perhaps all you need to do is change the XML declaration. Or convert the document to UTF-8 encoding. In any case, none of these can be done in XSLT.

Comment: I tried changing the xml prolong @encoding to 'iso-8859-1', and the xslt trans 
 was able to run without a parse error, but it caused a bunch of very standard chars, such as open and close quotes to come up as the unknown. The find/replace needs to be done prior to the xslt transformation, but I'm having trouble identifying those chars in any way other than the java char test I showed

Comment: Whether you replace the XML declaration or the bytes that aren't encoded per the declaration, you have to know the actual character encoding. Only the file writer knows what it is.

Comment: An editor that is able to read the file and correctly display the `¼` character, should also be able to tell you what the actual encoding is (obviously, it is **not** `iso-8859-1`). IMHO, you should concentrate on that instead of hunting for "bad characters" which are perfectly good characters being misrepresented by a mistaken choice of encoding.

Comment: @michael An editor would only show one possibility, would probably not say if the whole file was decodable "correctly" and would only have the current sample to work from. But, it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Taking "Input is not proper UTF-8" at face value and that "¼" is 0xC2 0xBC in UTF-8, 
and taking "indicate encoding !" at face value, I'd say you should go back to the source of the file or specification or whatever for information and tell your XSLT processor the character encoding of the file.

Okay, now that you've shown the XML declaration says UTF-8, you have a file that is invalid. No XSLT processor is obliged to handle it at all. Send it back to the originator.

Comment: sorry not to have provided more clarity...please see further edits. thanks!